# How can I configure my Web App in Windows Azure to redirect the requests to different VMs based on the request URL?

Tags: linux, azure, redirect

On Microsoft Azure, I have two Linux virtual machines (One is Ubuntu, another is CentOS) that are running the same RESTful service. These two virtual machines are running in the same vnet.

Now I created a Web Application and would like this web app to redirect the client requests to these two virtual machines, based on the format of request URL, for example:

- When `http://myapp.azurewebsite.com:8080/api/customers` coming in, the request will be redirected to Ubuntu server
- When `http://myapp.azurewebsite.com:8080/api/orders` coming in, the request should be redirected to CentOS server

How can I do this in Azure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure webapp runs on IIS. You can use URL rewriting to create rules in `Web.config` to rewrite one URL to another.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect request to Ubuntu">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.myapp.azurewebsite.com:8080/api/customers$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://ubuntu-server/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirect request to CentOS">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.myapp.azurewebsite.com:8080/api/orders$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://CentOS-server/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>          
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This seems to be a good idea. I will have a try on it. Moreover, if I need to distribute the request not only based on the URL but also need to be based on the VM work load, what should I do in Azure to achieve this?

Comment: Currently for two VMs, each request will be redirected to the certain VM, so there is no need to add work load solution. But if you have more than two VMs and multiple VMs could response to the same request, you could try [load balancer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-overview/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Azure Application Gateway](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/) which is a layer 7 external facing load balancer. It has various features you might find useful.

Referring to your requirement, application gateway lets you create server pools which will have requests directed to them according to URL. See ["Create an application gateway using URL based routing"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/application-gateway-create-url-route-arm-ps/) for more info on how to setup it up.

[image]